# Grab only part of the string at dynamic location

Tags: c#, .net

I have string file with content like this

```
string a = "12,1,______,_,__;1,23,122;"
```

I want to grab only this integer value `23`. Problem is that this conntent is dynamic and I it's lenght can be changed, so this string a can easily be in the next iteration like

```
string a = "12,1,______,_,__;11,2,1;"
```

In this case I would grab integer 2.

Comment: Is the format always the same - i.e., 4 commas, 1 semi-colon, 2 commas, 1 semi-colon?

Comment: @Tim yes, it's always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the structure is always the same, then:

Split the string, and grab the element before last.

```
var array1 =  a.Split(';');

// check the array length if it's needed to avoid 
// IndexOutOfRangeException exception
var array2 =  array1[1].Split(',');

var yourNumber = array2[array2.Length - 2]
```

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring error checking for a minute, this would work:

```
string a = "12,1,______,_,__;11,2,1;"
int i = Int32.Parse(String.Split(',')[5])
```

If this is the route you will go, you should take extra care to verify your input. Check the length of the array reutrned from `Split`, and verify that the 5th value can indeed be parsed to an `int`.

Comment: Are you sure about `6`th array element? I think it's 5th.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=;\d*,)\d*(?=,\d*;)
```

Sample usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = "12,1,______,_,__;1,23,122;";
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=;\d*,)\d*(?=,\d*;)");
        Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(a).Value);            
        a = "12,1,______,_,__;11,2,1;";
        Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(a).Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var number = a.split(",")[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

another option is to split the text into array (if they have same pattern):

```
var output = a.Split(",;".ToCharArray());
var value = output[theIndex]; // get the index you want
```